# Whats the name of extra selectors like :contains, :selected etc.?

Tags: jquery

You can use selectors like `:contains` fo find out if the currently selected option in a select contains a specific text, e.g.

```
var $el = $('#myselect option:contains("yes"):selected').length > 0 ? true : false;
```

I try to figure out more about these selectors, but I don't know how they are called to google them. Where can I inform myself?

Comment: Check [jquery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Thx, I was searching for this. I also found this: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called Pseudo-classes.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

---

Some used by jquery may not actually be available standard CSS.

For example `contains` isn't a thing - but `has` is